Oauth Sign-in (Google & Apple)
I am designing a SaaS web app, and i am implementing google and Apple sign-in features which allow first time users to create an account and returning used to login.
I have successfully setup google sign-in button and associated functionality. I can indeed register and login.
However I am trying to do the same for Apple sign-in, currently I can proceed to the Login page > select my Apple account > provide a password or Face ID, it turns into a tick and then redirects, at which point, I receive a 400’error bad request and a message saying missing CSRF token..
Any ideas? I’ve attempted to fix this 40+ times in the last 24 hours!
the code through ChatGPT. The recommendation was to disable to CSRF function which is the complete opposite of what is needed.
I have started create modules for my
Code so google auth is in my main app.py whilst Apple_auth is in its on.py file.
My developer accounts are setup with the right redirect URL etc

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
